# Уникально идентифицировать пользователя

Tags: python, django

Всем добрый день! Появилась необходимость уникально идентифицировать пользователя, притом не испоьзуя регистрацию. Т.е. пришел анонимный юзер - и нужно записать ему в сессию какой-то идентификатор. Есть идея писать рандомную строку, но вдруг эти строки совпадут у разных пользователей(шанс хоть мизерный, но есть)?
Отсюда вопрос, какие уникальные данные можно получить от пользователя, что бы потом их зашифровать и записать в сессию? Приветствуются все здравые соображения, спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Строить хэш от IP + timestamp + случайное число.
2. Использовать [UUID](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html)

Comment: 3. Впихивать в хэш информацию из заголовков HTTP. Тот же User-agent. Как приятный побочный эффект - пользователь не сможет склонировать куки в другие браузеры на своей же машине.

Comment: Кажется мы докопались до истины :)

Answer (score 1):

Если ты берешь хэш от чего-то, то в любом случае возможна коллизия. А чем не вариант выдавать просто последовательные числа?

Comment: Что бы выдавать последовательные числа, нужно как минимум хранить число юзеров в базе - а это лишний геморой.

Comment: главное только явно их пользователю не передавать, а то появится соблазн их модифицировать и попытаться достучатся до других сессий. С другой стороны, стоит посчитать, сколько будет пользователей всего, может стоит использовать 64 бита или два 64битных числа.

Answer (score 1):

http://javascript.ru/unsorted/id - идеи были. Правда, не по отношению к питону.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю!

Answer (score 0):

Можете по приходу юзера, запоминать Unix время, в секундах. И кодировать его либо в base64, либо в md5=)

Comment: А если придут одновременно 2 пользователя? Проект предполагается высоконагруженный. Может какие-то данные IP и т.д. можно получить?  
Как вариант - "склеить" время прихода ещё с чем-то рандомным и от этого взять хэш. Что думаете насчёт этого?

Comment: Почему бы и нет. Это называется "соль"=)  
Можете просто генерировать число от 1 до 10 и складывать два хэша. Уникальность близится к 100%

Comment: Я про это и думал, но всё же хочется добиться полной уникальности за счёт каких-то дополнительных технических параметров юзера, что-ли. Подождём ещё идей.

Answer (score 0):

В базе данных создать поле которое будет содержать число. Посетитель зашел на сайт, делаем UPDATE на +1 и возвращаем число. Склеиваем полученое число IP и time(), шифруем в md5. А еще лучше шифровать в base64 а потом md5.

Comment: Я уже тут писал в комментариях, что хранить это число в базе - лишний гемор. Дополнительные запросы не есть хорошо - поэтому лучше обойтись без них.

Answer (score 0):

Ради бога , придумайте сами. Там миллионы вариантов на уникальный идентификатор. Знайте одно, md5 не повторяется. Берите `unix time` прихода, как говорилось выше, хешируй, но когда впихиваешь в базу, проверяй нету ли там такого ид, если есть просто сделай md5(uid+time) uid того который уже есть и вуаля.

Answer (score -1):

А как насчет тех кто ходит с работы, у них часто будут одинаковые IP в одной оргонизации. Единственное что уникально почти у всех ПК это mac а если к нему добовлять один из выше перечисленных вариантов то всё будет ок.